# Copying text from pastebin to a variable c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a program which will copy data from a link and then save it to a variable. I mean I have link like `<https://pastebin.com/raw/2BVSSFVF>` and I want my program to load this text to my variable, is that possible?

Comment: I downvoted this question because you have not shown any effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Sure, get an HTTP library (like `curl`) and it will be all done there.

Comment: Are you planning on using pastebin as your personal database for your proprietary 'product'?

Comment: The question is a little ambiguous as currently worded. Do you want to copy text from the link itself? Or do you want to actually follow the link and download the file that the link refers to? I assume the latter, but please clarify to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that you want to follow the link and download what it refers to...

Strictly speaking the answer to the question "is that possible?" is simply "yes".

It could be done by scraping the webpages themselves or more ideally if pastebin has an API you can call. Some brief googling indicates pastebin might have a REST API.

So your next steps are to research:

- That pastebin API.
- The concept of APIs, REST, HTTP, etc in general if you're not familiar with those.
- Any libraries which can call such an API from C++

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cpr/cpr.h>
using namespace cpr;
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    auto r = Get(Url{ "ur link" });
    cout << r.text << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

- 

I think i dealt with this problem very well i post it here if some beginner would have such problem like me he can just use my code.